# Nothing happen when I use the code “imageCapture.takePicture” of CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm trying to explore cameraX beta version.

I'm stuck in my implementation.
**imageCapture.takePicture()** imageCapture is null.

```
        // Bind the CameraProvider to the LifeCycleOwner
    val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {

    // CameraProvider
    val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

    // ImageCapture
    imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
        .build()


        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()

        try {
            // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
            // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, imageCapture)
        } catch(exc: Exception) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

    // Create output file to hold the image
    photoFile = createFile(externalMediaDirs.first(), FILENAME, PHOTO_EXTENSION)

    // Setup image capture metadata
    val metadata = Metadata().apply {

        // Mirror image when using the front camera
        isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
    }
    // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
    outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile)
        .setMetadata(metadata)
        .build()

    // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has been taken
    imageCapture?.takePicture(
        outputOptions, cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = output.savedUri ?: Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri")

            }
        })
  }
```

(I don't use onClickListener)

My function is called by a service.

If I remove cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable I get Not bound to a valid Camera

I use camerax beta version

Answer (score 2):

The `ImageCapture` use case doesn't currently work on its own. It has to be used in combination with at least a `Preview` or `ImageAnalysis` use case. This might change in future versions of CameraX. For now, you can check the documentation on [supported use case combinations](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases).

A simple fix to your problem would be to add an `ImageAnalysis` use case, its `Analyzer` can just immediately close the images it receives.

```
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
      .build()
      .apply {
            setAnalyzer(executor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { image ->
            image.close()
        })
      }

// Then bind both the imageAnalysis and ImageCapture
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, imageCapture, imageAnalysis)
```